# sonata admin.datagrid.pager.countresults not count All elements

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

i see code

```
<label class="checkbox" for="{{ admin.uniqid }}_all_elements">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="all_elements" id="{{ admin.uniqid }}_all_elements">
                                                {{ 'all_elements'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
                                                ({{ admin.datagrid.pager.countResults() }})
                                            </label>
```

in base_list.html.twig

it execute like is expected action for all items but count only current page results ...

this is heppen only when i try setup default order

```
protected function configureDefaultSortValues(array &$sortValues): void
    {
        // display the first page (default = 1)
//        $sortValues[DatagridInterface::PAGE] = 1;

        // reverse order (default = 'ASC')
        $sortValues[DatagridInterface::SORT_ORDER] = 'DESC';

        // name of the ordered field (default = the model's id field, if any)
        $sortValues[DatagridInterface::SORT_BY] = 'id';
    }
```

when i comment this function counter works fine...

possible to fix it ?

its sonata admin 4,3 postgress db , symfony 6